# SSIS ForEach Loop behaviour

Tags: foreach, ssis, enumerator, foreach-loop-container

This is typical ForEach container behaviour:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypx7H.png]

However, if I do whats shown in the image below, the Execute SQL task never executes, how can i do this behaviour? I do not have to use ForEach container if some other type of container will allow me to do this.

The for each loop essentially loops through files in multiple subdirectories in a folder. Based on which folder the loop is in, it populates a variable. this variable is used in the connectors from "some script" task to "task a" and "task b" to decide which task will run. So it is possible that both tasks will run if files are detected in the folders associated with the tasks.

What I really need is for both task a and b to go to the same database task upon completion.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuPV3.png]

Comment: THANK YOU for adding the inline images :)

Comment: Do you really need task A and B to potentially fire in parallel?

Comment: No, they will never fire in parallel, the foreach loop selects a path based on which folder it is in.

Comment: In your comments below "So it is possible that both tasks will run if files are detected in the folders associated with the tasks" that comment is intended to apply across the entirety of the Foreach Loop running, not within a iteration? If so, then my answer holds true. If A and B could both fire for a single file iteration, then you'd need to restructure your precedent constraints.

Comment: I think i phrased my statement in a confusing manner. The for each loop will select a path one at a time based on which folder the for each loop is in. Your comments got me thinking down a path by which i finally found a solution to the problem... Thank You!

Comment: My reason for changing your question title is that your question is about precedent constraint behaviour. The fact that it's nested inside a Foreach loop does not matter. The logic is the same whether it's at the root Control Flow level or nested inside a Sequence or For Loop container

Answer (score 1):

You have two output paths from "Some Script Task". Those are connected to "task A" and "task b" via a precedent constraint. That precedent constraint is green - so success but it also has a glyph/adornment attached so that indicates there is also an expression that must be satisfied for that that constraint to be satisfied.

I assume that only A or b fires, right?

So, since only A or b could ever run, then the "Update result in DB for task" will be waiting forever for *both* of them to complete.

The resolution then is to change the multiple constraints section of the precedent constraint leading into that Execute SQL Task to go from `Logical AND` to `Logical OR`. Double click either connector and change it there. Both should now show as a green dashed line.

Comment: A bit more detail: the for each loop essentially loops through files in multiple subdirectories in a folder. Based on which folder the loop is in, it populates a variable. this variable is used in the connectors from "some script" task to "task a" and "task b" to decide which task will run. So it is possible that both tasks will run if files are detected in the folders associated with the tasks.

Comment: what i really need is for both task a and b to go to the same database task upon completion.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be the solution:

[image: Foo]